# If option selected do something

Tags: javascript

I have form. I want to do something, if the certain  option is selected. I try this

```js
if (document.getElementById('order-select').value == "Услуга") {
  alert("blabla");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="order-select">
  <option value="Услуга" class="item-1">Услуга</option>
  <option value="Строительный проект" class="item-2">Строительный проект</option>
</select>
```

Problem : I want to alert every time, when option is selected.
Need help

Comment: Show your event handler. (or add one if you haven't) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to attach an event listener for the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

When the event is fired, you can access the element through the [`target` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) on the [`event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

```js
document.getElementById('order-select').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  if (e.target.value === "Услуга") {
    alert('Selected');
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="order-select">
  <option class="item-1">--Select--</option>
  <option value="Услуга" class="item-2">Услуга</option>
  <option value="Строительный проект" class="item-3">Строительный проект</option>
</select>
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/0aLumo9o/)

```
document.getElementById('order-select').addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  if (e.target.value === "Услуга") {
    alert('Selected');
  }
});
```